# My magento database keeps crashing and doesn't log any errors

Tags: magento2, database

I'm using magento 2 and mariadb 10.4 on plesk with centos 7 and my mysql configuration file is below. How can I enable all logging such as slow query logging, all query logging, and all error logging? What other places can I check to see why my database is crashing? Am I missing anything perhaps?

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=127.0.0.1
#bind-address = ::
skip_name_resolve
local-infile=0
open_files_limit=10000
max_connections=1024
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

But as you can see from my mariadb log below, it barely shows any errors and my database has crashed at least 3 times today

```
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.21-MariaDB) starting as process 12533 ...
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0G
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1619370556356 and 1619370556356 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1619370556366 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-02-02 15:21:39 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-02-02 15:21:45 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2017-02-02 15:21:45 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2017-02-02 15:21:56 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-02-02 15:21:56 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-02-02 15:21:56 140044698675392 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log sequence number 1619370556366
2017-02-02 15:21:57 140034078381824 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-02-02 15:21:57 140044698675392 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-02-02 15:21:57 140044698675392 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2017-02-02 15:21:57 140044698675392 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2017-02-02 15:21:57 140044698675392 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2017-02-02 15:21:57 140044698442496 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2017-02-02 15:21:57 140044698442496 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
```

UPDATE: I made a few changes in the configuration file and I can see information about the crash. I'm pasting it below because I don't have a clue why it is crashing based on the information it is telling me

```
InnoDB: ###### Diagnostic info printed to the standard error stream
InnoDB: Error: semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds
InnoDB: We intentionally crash the server, because it appears to be hung.
2017-03-27 08:10:15 7f2fb3bfe700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139842855888640 in file srv0srv.cc line 2402
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
170327  8:10:15 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=54
max_threads=102
thread_count=46
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 550938 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x48400
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/mysqld terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7f322ac4b597]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x10c750)[0x7f322ac49750]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x10e507)[0x7f322ac4b507]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_addr_resolve+0x48)[0x7f322d6f0c28]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x1c2)[0x7f322d6dd2a2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x305)[0x7f322d2009d5]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100)[0x7f322c819100]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f322ab725f7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f322ab73ce8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x812086)[0x7f322d45c086]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5)[0x7f322c811dc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f322ac33ced]

2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0G
2017-03-27  8:10:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-03-27  8:10:44 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-03-27  8:10:44 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2104090103665
2017-03-27  8:11:00 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 99 .ibd/.isl files
2017-03-27  8:11:16 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 1452 .ibd/.isl files
2017-03-27  8:11:20 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2017-03-27  8:11:20 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=2104090234368
InnoDB: 31 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 21108 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 552931328
2017-03-27  8:11:22 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 21667 pages from redo log
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930617, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140431824124096 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.35-80.0 started; log sequence number 2104096291801
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930617 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930614, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930614 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930611, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930611 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930603, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930603 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930592, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930592 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930575, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930575 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930158, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930158 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930156, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930156 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930150, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930150 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930149, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930149 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930136, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930136 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930090, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930090 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552930062, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552930062 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552929750, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552929750 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552929749, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552929749 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552929722, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552929722 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552929701, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552929701 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552929684, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552929684 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552929550, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552929550 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928657, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928657 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928272, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928272 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928271, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928271 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928237, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928237 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928235, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928235 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928234, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928234 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928004, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928004 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928003, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928003 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552928002, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552928002 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552927931, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:43 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552927931 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:43 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552927750, 1 rows to undo
2017-03-27  8:11:44 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552927750 completed
2017-03-27 08:11:44 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 552927705, 21078 rows to undo

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 1 2 32017-03-27  8:12:28 140421162309376 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-03-27  8:12:28 140431824124096 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-03-27  8:12:28 140431824124096 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2017-03-27  8:12:28 140431824124096 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2017-03-27  8:12:28 140431824124096 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2017-03-27  8:12:28 140431824124096 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2017-03-27  8:12:28 140431823588096 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

2017-03-27 08:12:28 7fb8d4fdf8c0  InnoDB: Error: table `tmp`.`#sql5e71_42d15_d` does not exist in the InnoDB internal
InnoDB: data dictionary though MySQL is trying to drop it.
InnoDB: Have you copied the .frm file of the table to the
InnoDB: MySQL database directory from another database?
InnoDB: You can look for further help from
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2017-03-27 08:12:28 7fb8d4fdf8c0  InnoDB: Error: table `tmp`.`#sql5e71_42d15_c` does not exist in the InnoDB internal
InnoDB: data dictionary though MySQL is trying to drop it.
InnoDB: Have you copied the .frm file of the table to the
InnoDB: MySQL database directory from another database?
InnoDB: You can look for further help from
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2017-03-27 08:12:28 7fb8d4fdf8c0  InnoDB: Error: table `tmp`.`#sql5e71_42d15_b` does not exist in the InnoDB internal
InnoDB: data dictionary though MySQL is trying to drop it.
InnoDB: Have you copied the .frm file of the table to the
InnoDB: MySQL database directory from another database?
InnoDB: You can look for further help from
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2017-03-27 08:12:29 7fb8d4fdf8c0  InnoDB: Error: table `tmp`.`#sql5e71_42d15_a` does not exist in the InnoDB internal
InnoDB: data dictionary though MySQL is trying to drop it.
InnoDB: Have you copied the .frm file of the table to the
InnoDB: MySQL database directory from another database?
InnoDB: You can look for further help from
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2017-03-27 08:12:29 7fb8d4fdf8c0  InnoDB: Error: table `tmp`.`#sql5e71_42d15_9` does not exist in the InnoDB internal
InnoDB: data dictionary though MySQL is trying to drop it.
InnoDB: Have you copied the .frm file of the table to the
InnoDB: MySQL database directory from another database?
InnoDB: You can look for further help from
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2017-03-27 08:12:29 7fb8d4fdf8c0  InnoDB: Error: table `tmp`.`#sql5e71_42d15_8` does not exist in the InnoDB internal
InnoDB: data dictionary though MySQL is trying to drop it.
InnoDB: Have you copied the .frm file of the table to the
InnoDB: MySQL database directory from another database?
InnoDB: You can look for further help from
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2017-03-27 08:12:29 7fb8d4fdf8c0  InnoDB: Error: table `tmp`.`#sql5e71_42d15_7` does not exist in the InnoDB internal
InnoDB: data dictionary though MySQL is trying to drop it.
InnoDB: Have you copied the .frm file of the table to the
InnoDB: MySQL database directory from another database?
InnoDB: You can look for further help from
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2017-03-27  8:12:29 140431824124096 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@u19362139' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2017-03-27  8:12:29 140431824124096 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.22-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2017-03-27  8:12:29 140431823588096 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2017-03-27  8:12:29 140421145523968 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-03-27  8:12:29 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
 4 5 6 72017-03-27  8:13:30 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 8 9 102017-03-27  8:14:30 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 11 12 132017-03-27  8:15:30 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 14 15 16 172017-03-27  8:16:30 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 18 19 20 212017-03-27  8:17:30 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 22 23 24 252017-03-27  8:18:30 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 26 27 28 292017-03-27  8:19:31 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 30 31 32 33 342017-03-27  8:20:31 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 35 36 37 382017-03-27  8:21:31 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 39 40 41 42 432017-03-27  8:22:31 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 44 45 46 472017-03-27  8:23:31 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 48 49 50 51 522017-03-27  8:24:32 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 53 54 55 562017-03-27  8:25:32 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 57 58 59 602017-03-27  8:26:32 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 61 62 632017-03-27  8:27:32 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 64 65 66 672017-03-27  8:28:32 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 68 69 70 712017-03-27  8:29:32 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 72 73 74 752017-03-27  8:30:33 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 76 77 78 792017-03-27  8:31:33 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 80 81 82 832017-03-27  8:32:33 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 84 85 86 872017-03-27  8:33:33 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 88 89 90 912017-03-27  8:34:33 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 92 93 94 95 962017-03-27  8:35:34 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
 97 98 99 1002017-03-27  8:36:34 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for 1 active transactions to finish
2017-03-27  8:36:39 140421304936192 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 552927705 completed
2017-03-27 08:36:39 7fb661ffe700  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2017-03-27  8:36:40 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2017-03-27  8:36:42 140431823588096 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2104154319438
2017-03-27  8:36:42 140431823588096 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Are you still using Magento?  Do you still need assistance?  Please see my profile, Network profile for contact info.

Comment: Are you still using Magento? Do you still need assistance? Please see my profile, Network profile for contact info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're running MaraiDB v10.4, but your log shows 10.1.22

I think this is the pertinent part of your log:

```
Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=54
max_threads=102
thread_count=46
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 550938 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x48400
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/mysqld terminated
```

Notice the server version at the top and the  error at the bottom about a buffer overflow.

Others have experienced similar bugs with v10.1.22 and other versions of 10.1 (such as here https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10349).

Perhaps at this point you'd be better off simply upgrading to the latest MariaDB version 10.2 here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-102/

Answer (score 0):

make sure this path is writeable:

```
/var/run/mariadb/
```

check if user `mysql` is your mysqld service user and it has write permissions to that path.
also check if there is any `selinux` or other protection is enabled in the system.

you can see any signs of failure for example in `/var/log/messages`

your config file is not complete.
run `mysqltuner.pl` to make sure you have adequate resources.

Comment: I made a few changes and I can see the log now but I am having trouble understanding it. I updated my post to show the log that I'm getting when the server crashes. Do you have any ideas what it means?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
# read_buffer_size      appears to be ~ 2M  leading with # spacebar
```

will use default value rather than this overprovisioning of RAM per CONNECTION

Please consider posting complete report from Mysqltuner.pl when available for additional helpful information related to your MySQL instance.  All their advice should be carefully researched before taking action.